# The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead, using Django

Tags: python, django, httpresponse, modelform

So, I am trying to display a form into my html using Django, it has to be a form that creates a new page in the database.
I am using ModelForm since I've read is the best way to provide the user with the tools to input data in the database.

in views.py:

```
       from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
       from django.http import HttpResponse
       from .models import Pages, PagesForm
       from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
       from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
       from django.contrib import messages
       from .forms import NewUserForm


def homepage(request):
    return render(request = request,
                  template_name='main/home.html',
                  context = {})
def pages(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PagesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass
            #nada, solo activa la validación
        else:
            form = PagesForm()    
            return render(request,
                        template_name='main/pages.html',
                        context = {"Pages":PagesForm.objects.all})
```

in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.forms import ModelForm
# Create your models here.


#Pages son entradas del diario
class Pages(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField("Published: ", default=datetime.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class PagesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pages
        fields = '__all__'
```

in pages.html:

```
{% extends "main/header.html" %}


{% block content %}
<div>
  {% for page in Pages %}
  <h2>Display recent pages</h2>
      <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
        <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
          <div class="card-content white-text">
            <span class="card-title">{{page.title}}</span>
            <p>{{page.published_date}}</p>
            <p>{{page.author}}</p>
            <p>{{page.content|safe}}</p>
            <div class="card-action">
              <a href="#">Leer más</a>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  {% endfor %}
</div>

<h2>Create a new page</h2>

<br>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button style="background-color:#F4EB16; color:blue" class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

I would appreciate some help, thank you very much !

Comment: And what if `if request.method == "POST":` is not `True`? What does it return then?

Answer (score 1):

change the view like this
    def pages(request):

```
   if request.method == "POST":
       form = PagesForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()

          #nada, solo activa la validación
          form = PagesForm()
          return render(request,
                    template_name='main/pages.html',
                    context = {"Pages":form})
   else:
       form = PagesForm()    
       return render(request,
                    template_name='main/pages.html',
                    context = {"Pages":form})
```